# R strftime() behavior

Tags: r, datetime

Below are listed two lines of code.  Both are identical expect for the day and time but only one works.  I am using R 3.1.

The following doesn't work:

```
DateTime2=strftime("08/13/2010 05:26:24.350", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS", tz="GMT")
```

Returns the following error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

But the following works:

```
DateTime2=strftime("08/02/2010 06:50:29.450", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS", tz="GMT")
```

The second line stores `DateTime2` as expected.

Any thoughts?

Comment: No error occurs for me with the first command.

Comment: Same for me. No error. What locale/timezone are you in?

Comment: My question got changed by Pascal! I didnt ask that question. My question concerns strftime not strptime.  Is anyone getting this error the way I asked before Pascal changed my question?

Answer (score 7):

What happens when you use `strftime`? Here is `strftime` code:

```
> strftime
function (x, format = "", tz = "", usetz = FALSE, ...) 
format(as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz), format = format, usetz = usetz, 
    ...)
<bytecode: 0xb9a548c>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

It calls `as.POSIXlt` and THEN format using the argument `format`.
If you call directly `as.POSIXlt` on your example without giving an argument `format`, here is what happens:

```
> as.POSIXlt("08/13/2010 05:26:24.350", tz="GMT")
Error in as.POSIXlt.character("08/13/2010 05:26:24.350", tz = "GMT") : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

The reason being that the code for `as.POSIXlt` is the following:

```
> as.POSIXlt.character
function (x, tz = "", format, ...) 
{
    x <- unclass(x)
    if (!missing(format)) {
        res <- strptime(x, format, tz = tz)
        if (nzchar(tz)) 
            attr(res, "tzone") <- tz
        return(res)
    }
    xx <- x[!is.na(x)]
    if (!length(xx)) {
        res <- strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d")
        if (nzchar(tz)) 
            attr(res, "tzone") <- tz
        return(res)
    }
    else if (all(!is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", 
        tz = tz))) || all(!is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS", 
        tz = tz))) || all(!is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", 
        tz = tz))) || all(!is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", 
        tz = tz))) || all(!is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d", 
        tz = tz))) || all(!is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y/%m/%d", 
        tz = tz)))) {
        res <- strptime(x, f, tz = tz)
        if (nzchar(tz)) 
            attr(res, "tzone") <- tz
        return(res)
    }
    stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
}
<bytecode: 0xb9a4ff0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

If no `format` is given, it tries a serie of common format, if none of them work it raises the error you got.

The reason for all that is that `strftime` (contrary to `strptime` hence the confusion) is not used to convert a character into a POSIXlt object but to turn a POSIXlt object into a character. From the help page for `strftime`:

> Value
>
> The format methods and strftime return character vectors representing
>   the time.

To do what you wanted to do, use `as.POSIXlt` directly as follows:

```
> as.POSIXlt("08/13/2010 05:26:24.350", tz="GMT", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2010-08-13 05:26:24 GMT"
```

**Edit:** FYI you're second line of code didn't work either:

```
strftime("08/02/2010 06:50:29.450", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS", tz="GMT")
[1] "02/20/0008 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding what `strftime` does. Its purpose is to change a `POSIXt` object to a character vector. So you should give `POSIXt` objects as argument to `strftime`. If you give a character vector, it tries to convert to `POSIXlt` before formatting it. The most important thing is that the `format` argument is not the format of the input string, *but it's the format you want as output*. For instance:

```
strftime(as.POSIXct("2014-10-20 12:14:50"), format = "%Y/%m")
#[1] "2014/10"
```

What happens in your case? Since you are providing character vector, `strftime` tries to convert it to a `POSIXlt` assuming you gave the date in some standard format. The first string, however, displays a `13` when in standard format you are supposed to provide the month. Since there are just 12 months, an error occurs. Note also how it converts the second date (which is very different from what it is supposed to mean).