# R strftime() only preserving date, not time

Tags: r, csv, timestamp

My R script reads in CSV data of two columns, where the columns are timestamps and scalar values, with:

```
data = read.csv(dataFilePath, colClasses=c("charDate", "numeric"))
```

My timestamps are formatted e.g. "5/14/14 13:14". The class `charDate` is defined to convert the timestamps:

```
setClass("charDate")
setAs("character", "charDate", function(from) strftime(from))
```

The datafiles I'm running are [here](https://github.com/numenta/NAB/tree/master/data). They all read in as expected, represented in the R dataframe `data` as e.g. "2014-05-14 13:14:00", except for those in the realTweets/ directory. Why? For realTweets/, the timestamps in `data` look like e.g. "2014-05-14", where the time info has not been preserved.

Comment: @RichardScriven the times are deleted after running the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with `strftime()`. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26481614/3765905), `strftime()` just wraps `as.POSIXlt()`. Using `as.POSIXlt()` directly fixed my problem:

```
setAs("character", "charDate", function(from) as.POSIXlt(from))
```